# Ютуб, Ютюб или Ютьюб?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, заимствования

Как правильно говорить: *Ютуб, Ютюб* или *Ютьюб*?

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, как бы кто ни изощрялся в произнесении заимствованного слова,  победит в конечном счёте русский звуковой строй, и все однозначно будут говорить "Ютуб".
Не хотелось бы только в будущем обнаружить в языке ещё одного нелягушку-немышонка типа "жюри", "брошюра" и "парашют".

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1. Самое популярное на YouTube (ютьюб, йотированный гласный, несклоняемое слово, соответствует английскому произношению).

Вариант 2. Смотреть на Ютубе (твердое произношение, русифицированный вариант, слово склоняется).

Comment: Почему нельзя смотреть на ютьюбе?

Comment: Ютуб - русифицированный вариант,  с русской графикой.  Ютьюб - неестественная запись слова, вряд ли утвердится эта графика,  вариант больше похож на фонетическую запись английского слова.

Comment: Вопрос-то был: как произносить?

Comment: А произносить, то есть читать,  надо по правилам: написано Ютуб, значит не "ютьюб".

Comment: Не существует правила переносить названия исключительно средствами транслитерации.
"Транслитерация применяется преимущественно по отношению к мёртвым языкам..."
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Транслитерация

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Практическая_транскрипция

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Англо-русская_практическая_транскрипция
(формально получится именно "ютьюб")

Comment: Речь идет не о транскрипции или транслитерации, а о возможности заимствования слова, то есть обеспечения соответствия его русской  фонетике и русской системе письма. (Транслитерация — это система точной передачи букв алфавита одного языка средствами иной графической системы, транскрипция — графическая запись звучания слова).

Comment: Для этого и применяется практическая транскрипция, которая учитывает наиболее существенные аспекты заимствований, будь то название или термин. Транслитерация в её рамках - частный приём, не всегда полезный в чистом виде (как и здесь). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: *написано Ютуб, значит не "ютьюб"* - на заборе тоже написано. Пишут как раз Ютюб. Но произносят ютьюб.

Answer (score 2):

Всё очень просто. Выбор произношения YouTube по-русски зависит от того, какому варианту следовать: британскому или американскому.
Британское произношение этого слово я бы передал как "ютьюб" или "ютъюб", Т там полумягкое, ближе к твёрдому. Американское произношение представляет что-то среднее между "ютюб" и "ютуб". Сравнить эти варианты можно здесь: [YouTube](http://forvo.com/word/youtube/#en). Первые два получили больше всего голосов и вполне показательны.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71258/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Answer (score 1):

Не фиксируется пока словарями - и не очень понятно, будет ли фиксироваться. Имя собственное, но очень специфическое. Полагаю, что в разговоре победит вариант Ютуб.

> Часто слышу, что русские произносят это слово с мягким "т". Хотя, если строго следовать правилам, здесь должен быть твердый согласный.

Каким правилам? В такой позиции Т даже в английском немного смягчается, что уж о русском-то о говорить... Cравните: бьюик, Компьютер, фьючерс. Нет, здесь смягчение обязательно, русская фонетика требует. А орфографический Ъ внутри корня применяется для считанных слов, просто так не стоит его рекомендовать.

Comment: Во всех ваших примерах т стоит в позиции перед теми гласными, после которых оно смягчается. После "у" в русском согласные не смягчаются. Слово "компьютер" произносится с твердым "т''.

Comment: утешение Путин утюг кутёж купюра...

Comment: Серж, причем тут т? Я про произношение согласных перед английским u. Как в tube.

Comment: В русском языке разделительный Ь не является показателем мягкости/твердости, согласный перед Ь может произноситься ка твердо, так и мягко (льет, пьет), но  разделительный Ь является показателем  последующего йотированного гласного (компьютер). Звук П в "компьютер" также, скорее, произносится твердо, так как он окружён твердыми соседями КО, ТЭ.

Comment: Серж имел в виду отсутствие смягчения во втором слоге, если первый заканчивается на -у (йу/ю) - в нашем слове таков первый слог -  в обоснование йУтУб (ютуб), но слова с таким смягчением в русском есть (самое похожее "утюг").

Comment: "Серж имел в виду отсутствие"  ну знаете.... Это конечно меняло бы дело, но из чего это видно? Вообще в русском значимая ассимиляция всегда регрессивная, а тут прогрессивная получается по-Вашему (ну или по Сержу, если вы его правильно поняли). И даже не ассимиляция, а какое-то странное явление, когда предшествующий(!) гласный(!) влияет на твердость последующего  согласного. У него и названия нет за ненадобностью... Да и не верю я, что кто-то вообще произносит "ютюбь","ютубь" etc. Пусть сам объяснит в вопросе, что он говорит не про Т, в про Б.

Comment: В утюге Г твердый, если это не падежная форма с флексией на гласную переднего ряда (и или е). Почему Вы решили, что он смягченный?

Comment: "звук П в "компьютер" также, скорее, произносится твердо," никак не могу согласиться. Я с большим напряжением воспроизвел там твердый П, но никогда подобного не слышал.

Comment: Насчет компьютера: там твердый "т'', а не п. Об этом я и говорил. Вы говорили про произношение согласных перед английским u, а я - про произношение согласных перед русским ''у".

Comment: behemothus, Александр меня понял правильно: в русском языке смягчение твердых происходит происходит перед е,ё, и ю,ю. Перед а, о, у, э согласные остаются твердыми, смягчения не происходит.

Comment: *"Александр меня понял правильно:"* Ну и общайтесь с ним, что вы мне-то рассказываете за русский язык?  ***"в русском языке смягчение твердых происходит происходит перед е,ё, и ю, ю"*** - Мне-то он пишет нечто совсем другое: ***"Серж имел в виду отсутствие смягчения во втором слоге, если первый заканчивается на -у (йу/ю)"*** Это как угодно можно понимать, только не так как Вы сейчас "перевели".

Comment: На всякий случай повторяю. Согласный перед "ью" во всех заимствованных английских словах смягчается в той или иной степени. Графически это должно передаваться как Ютьюб. Первый слог (Ю) не имеет никакого отношения к смягчению начального согласного второго (тьюб). Это было бы прогрессивной ассимиляцией(?), которая вообще не свойственна русскому. Не знаю, что еще тут надо говорить. Надо ли писать "Ютьюб" вместо "Ютуб"? наверное надо. Но этого момента я тут не касался, да и вообще никто, вроде, не касался. А произношение "Т" однозначно (для меня) должно быть мягким.

Answer (score 1):

Я воспринимаю нормально все варианты, кроме "ютуб" - уж больно прямолинейная транслитерация; сам произношу "ютюб", чтобы не напрягаться переходом на произношение из другого языка (английское ближе к "ютйуб", в американском вместо "йу" слышится что-то вроде немецкого ü). В рамках русского языка "ютюб" легче произносится и проще записывается, чем "ютьюб" или "ютъюб" (последнее неудобно произносить - даже слово "адъютант" произносится в русском мягко, а с -тъю- слов, возможно, даже нет).
Соответственно, я за "**мягкий"** вариант.

**P.S.** Если вспомнить историю похожего по написанию и произношению термина, **tuner** (радиоприёмник без встроенного звукового усилителя), его поначалу педантично писали как "тьюнер", но позже остановились на "**тюнер**".

Comment: А есть ли в русском какие-н. другие слова, которые произносятся мягко - например, перед у,о,а ?

Comment: бульон, лосьон, каньон, бриллиант, радиус...

Comment: А-а, да, вспомнил. Это французские заимствование, и поэтому сохраняют произношение источника. Спасибо! Так, скорее всего, обстоит дело с Ютуб.

Comment: Я лично произношу ЮтУб. Мне непривычно произносить это слово с мягким "т". Да и многие русскоязычные армяне (которые живут здесь) произносят это слово с твердым "т".

Comment: В слове "бульон" мягкое произношение Л перед О обозначается с помощью Ь.

Comment: Чтобы мягко произносить, надо "мягко" писать: Ютюб, но никто так не пишет. Кстати, Ютуб - это, скорее, "тубус", чем "тюбик"

Comment: бульон и лосьон - там Ь, бриллиант и радиус - это перед И, а не у, о, а. А вот я придумал пример: "фольклор".